# Filling the Clipboard with content covering multiple cells which itself are containing line breaks (Alt-Enter) in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, newline, clipboard

I'm working on a VBA Excel Add-In to provide users with clipboard text containing values from multiple cells, but also having multiple lines within a cell. Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution which keeps cell seperations as well as line breaks within a cell, correctly. Is there any way of modifying my exemplary Sub "ClipboardDoesntWork" in order to deliver the same clipboard as Sub "CopyPasteWorks" but without using the workaround of filling cells and copying them?

```
Public Sub CopyPasteWorks()

     Dim text1a As String
     Dim text1b As String
     Dim text2a As String
     Dim text2b As String
     Dim firstcell As String
     Dim secondcell As String
          
     Columns("A:C").Clear
     Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 20
          
     text1a = "Line 1 in Cell 1"
     text1b = "Line 2 in Cell 1"
     text2a = "Line 1 in Cell 2"
     text2b = "Line 2 in Cell 2"
     
     firstcell = text1a & vbLf & text1b
     secondcell = text2a & vbLf & text2b
     
     Range("A1").Value = firstcell
     Range("A2").Value = secondcell  
     Range("A1:A2").Copy     
     MsgBox "Clipboard filled with content of two cells!" & vbLf & "(covering two lines, each)"

End Sub

Public Sub ClipboardDoesntWork()
'NOTE! Code requires library reference: Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

     Dim text1a As String
     Dim text1b As String
     Dim text2a As String
     Dim text2b As String
     Dim firstcell As String
     Dim secondcell As String
     Dim objData As New DataObject
          
     text1a = "Line 1 in Cell 1"
     text1b = "Line 2 in Cell 1"
     text2a = "Line 1 in Cell 2"
     text2b = "Line 2 in Cell 2"
     
     firstcell = text1a & vbLf & text1b
     secondcell = text2a & vbLf & text2b
     
     objData.SetText firstcell & vbCrLf & secondcell
     objData.PutInClipboard
     MsgBox "Clipboard filled with content of four cells!"

End Sub
```

I tried various versions of line feeds and/or carrier returns (vbLf, vbCr, vbCrLf, vbNewLine, chr(10)) and different techniques of filling the clipboard (MSForms.DataObject, API method), but nothing works so far.
(My final Code is generating the clipboard string by joing array fields (coming from a database query), but the hurdle I couldn't take can also be demonstrated well with the simplified codes shown above.)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Where do you want to paste the data from the clipboard?

Comment: If you **ABSOLUTELY** need the data in your clip board, you would either: Stuff all the data into one cell, then copy that cell. Or, open a .txt document to combine all your data.

Comment: The Add-In allows users to retrieve database query results from any excel sheet. The user (already) can initiate a query via context menue based on multiple selected cells and gets the results (one for each selected cell) into the clipboard. It's not predictable, where the user will need to have the answer pasted to, so I need to use the clipboard. The existant Add-In works perfectly so far, but seperates multiple answers for one cell by semicolons. In future it is required to seperate them by line breaks. Asking back the user or pasting it into a predefined range is no option.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have the answer.
**Close your File Browser.**
Apparently `.PutInClipboard` doesn't work in Windows 10 while browser is open.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClipboardDoesntWork()
'NOTE! Code requires library reference: Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

     Dim text1a As String
     Dim text1b As String
     Dim text2a As String
     Dim text2b As String
     Dim firstcell As String
     Dim secondcell As String
     Dim objData As DataObject
     Set objData = New DataObject
          
     text1a = "Line 1 in Cell 1"
     text1b = "Line 2 in Cell 1"
     text2a = "Line 1 in Cell 2"
     text2b = "Line 2 in Cell 2"
     
     firstcell = text1a & Chr(10) & text1b
     secondcell = text2a & Chr(10) & text2b
     
     objData.SetText firstcell & Chr(10) & secondcell
     objData.PutInClipboard
     MsgBox "Clipboard filled with content of four cells!"

End Sub
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help!
What I need to get filled into the clipboard is "Line 1 in Cell 1" <Alt+Enter> "Line 2 in Cell 1" <Enter> "Line 1 in Cell 2" <Alt+Enter> "Line 2 in Cell 2". The pasted content should appear in only two cells. Please try out Sub "CopyPasteWorks". Here the clipboard is filled exactly like it should be, but unfortunately the content is filled into predefined cells, first.
If there's no better solution, I will prepare the content in a hidden sheet, first and use the copy command like in CopyPasteWorks. However, I'm curious if anybody knows, how to avoid this.

Comment: Well, this is ugly, but might work: `Set WS = Worksheets.Add <br> 
     With WS <br> 
        .Range("A1").Value = text1a & Chr(10) & text1b <br> 
        .Range("A2").Value = text2a & Chr(10) & text2b <br> 
        .Range("A1:A2").Copy <br>`

Comment: My solution (more or less exactly, what Cameron Critchlow recommended above): 
I added a "vbVeryHidden"-sheet into the AddIn, which I first clear completely (from former runs. Then the cells are filled with the required content in the final format, that users need to have in the clipboard. Then I use the copy range command...